# Blockly Support for Class Types

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I am using blockly in my application to achieve scratch Programming and I have requirement to for creating Complex Types and assigning to Variables while creating them.

I have seen this blockly Pull request but this feature not yet available

[image: Not I am able to create variables for string types and cannot create object for complex types]

Comment: Hey did you managed to progress with that?